# Need troubleshoot fix my Raspberri Pi camera

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, motion, picamera, raspberry-pi-desktop

So my MotionEye setup works fine, but after like 24 hours everyday, when I go connect the IP address it won't connect for some reason... And I can see that the Raspberry Pi3 and the Camera is working, but I can't connect to it using MotionEye! At first I thought it might be a heat issue, but I have now installed heat pads in my Pi and the Camera, but the issue is not fixed.

Had the camera for a month now and now got issues..

No error code I just can't connect to it! I see that the Raspberry Pi3 and it's camera is on too..

Comment: Seems this has nothing to do with MotionEye but with networking. What Raspbian version do you use? Buster? How is the RasPi connected? Wired or wireless? Please edit your question and add the missing information.

Comment: Hello, can you still `ping` the Pi and does it's MAC/IP address still appear in the `arp -a` table? I ask as I once had a problem where a WiFi router was not bridging ARP replies correctly so the IP address would stop working after a while (until I `ping`'ed my PC from the Pi or manually added it to the PCs arp table).

Comment: @Ingo I have motionEyeOS version 20190911 installed to my Raspberry Pi. I don't know what is a Buster. The RasPi is connected to my Wifi wirelessly.

Comment: OK, I understand. You do not use any version of Raspbian (the current stable version is Raspbian Buster, Its predecessor is Raspbian Stretch). But you tagged with **raspberry-pi-desktop**. That cannot run on a Raspberry Pi. So what are you using now?

Comment: @Ingo As I said I have motionEyeOS version 20190911 installed to my Raspberry Pi.. Or what u asking?

Comment: You tagged the question with [raspberry-pi-desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/). It cannot run on a Raspberry Pi3. It can only run on a PC or Mac. So my question is: do you use a PC or a Mac? For what do you need that?

Comment: @Ingo I use a PC.

Comment: It is really difficult to get information to understand what you are doing. But let me try again to ask: **for what do you need that?**

Comment: @Ingo Need what? I need the camera for security.

Comment: The question was about **raspberry-pi-desktop**. But it's ok. I give up.

Comment: When you say "I see that the Raspberry Pi3 and it's camera is on too" do you mean by checking its LEDs? Can you ping its IP address? (run "ping X.X.X.X" from a command prompt) It's possible its IP may be changing. Usually your router will give you a list of device addresses, have you looked at this? Is there anything on the PI's screen if you leave it connected to a monitor?

Comment: @Fred No the IP is staying the same. Im thinking now if the problem is with the power plug. Whats the recommended power for Pi3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by powering the Raspberry Pi with a  5.1V, 2.5A power plug now its been running well 24/7 ever since.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.